# How do I select a particular row of a table from database?

Tags: java, jsp

I have this script in my html, if the status is `0`, it can click the button "`evaluate`", if not, button will be `hidden`.

`$('#table-content').append` retrieves all the data from my database using while loop inside a scriplet.

I'm trying to get what row from the table did the user clicked but I keep on getting the last row from the table.

```
<%
    while (records.next()){
            String regisID = records.getString("registrationID");
            String courseName = records.getString("courseName");
            String profName = records.getString("professorName");
            String courseTime = records.getString("courseTime");
            String SID = records.getString("SID");
            int status = records.getInt("status");
    %>
        var num = <%= status %>;
        var btn = "";
        if(num===0)
            btn = "<td style='width: 10%;'><button type='button' id='evaluateBtn' class='btn btn-block btn-primary'>Evaluate</button></td>";
        else
            btn = "<td style='width: 10%;'><button type='button' class='btn btn-block btn-success disabled'>Done</button></td>";
        
        $('#table-content').append(
                "<tr>"+
                "<td style='width: 20%;'><%= courseName %></td>"+
                "<td style='width: 25%;'><%= profName %></td>"+
                "<td style='width: 20%;'> <%= courseTime %></td>"+
                btn+
                "</tr>"
        );
        
        $("#evaluateBtn").click(function() {
            var form = document.createElement("form");
            document.body.appendChild(form);
            $(form).append("<input type='hidden' name='registrationID' value='<%= regisID %>'/>");
            $(form).append("<input type='hidden' name='courseName' value='<%= courseName %>'/>");
            $(form).append("<input type='hidden' name='SID' value='<%= SID %>'/>");
            form.action="http://localhost:8080/NewDesignV1/evaluate.action";
            form.method="post";
            form.submit();
            $(form).remove();
        });
        <%} %>
```

If I click `evaluate` button, I want to retrieve **subject**, **professor** and **time**. Take note that I'm looping table rows using while loop that's why if I click on `evaluate` button, I keep on getting the details of the last row

[See attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TC6tt.jpg)

Comment: *"retrieves all the data"* Where is the code? --- What is `regisID`, `courseName`, and `SID`? --- Assuming the shown code is inside a loop that makes those available, you're create N button with `id='evaluateBtn'`, which is so very wrong, since IDs are supposed to be unique. You then attach a `click` handler to button with that `id` (well, which one?) and it builds a `form` with a hidden field with value `regisID`, but which `regisID`? Presumably, every row has a different value. Re-think what you're doing, and perhaps look into HTML `data` attributes.

Comment: Why not just register a clicklistener on the respective table rows? Or attach an ID to the button you're already appending?

Comment: @Andreas see edit, I create the button because I want to disable the button if the status is 1(meaning this is already evaluated) and if 0, redirect to a servlet

Comment: If only one button will actually be enabled and given that ID, then perhaps you should only register the `click` handler once too, on the same condition (`num===0`).

Answer (score 0):

To my Understanding, You want to select a corresponding row to a clicked button. As you said you are receiving records from a server and Iterating through JQuery. As per my knowledge , ID element should be Unique in the Document and there are multiple ID elements created in loop. You can use Class instead of ID. To select current table row you can use following code.
This is Just Example :

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td class="one">A</td>
   <td style='width: 20%;' class="courseName">ABc</td>
    <td><button class="the-btn">
     Click
    </button></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td class="one">b</td>    
   <td style='width: 20%;' class="courseName">DEF</td>
   <td><button class="the-btn">
     Click
   </button></td>
 </tr>
```

And JS :

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.the-btn').on('click',function(){
       alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.courseName').text());
   });
});
```

Here is [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m9t9m18p/1/)

Comment: I'm iterating using while loop and I already have class which contains my css. How will I manage that?

Comment: try binding your click event to the class instead of ID because ID must be unique on HTML Document .for more Information go to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp .
You can bind click event to one of existing classes of button(if those classes are not being used any other place on page) OR you can add new class to the button ie  $('.btn-block').on('click',function(){ /*your Code here*/ });

Comment: One thing more , You should keep your click event out of while loop and access your elements through The HTML DOM